# export table list to pdf in yii2 using kartik mpdf

Tags: yii2, mpdf

I am trying to generate pdf file for list of data.Here I have used kartik mpdf extension.I have 3 combo box in my report view.On click of search button data list in my table and when i click on print button all my buttons appear in my pdf file as well as buttons.Here I want to skip combo box and buttons.Also i want to style my generated pdf file.

My view code :

```
    <?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use app\models\FiscalYear;
use app\models\CodeValue;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\CompanyInfo;
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'Company-report',
        'action' => ['company-report'],
        'method' => 'POST',

    ]); ?>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <?= $form->field($model, 'fy_id')->dropDownList(
                ArrayHelper::map(FiscalYear::getAllFiscalYr(),'fy_id','fiscal_yr'),
                ['prompt'=>Selct Fiscal Year.।'])?>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3">
                     <?= $form->field($model, 'sfcl_id')->dropDownList(
                ArrayHelper::map(Company::getCompanyData(),'company_id','company_name'),
                ['prompt'=>'Select Company'] )?>

            </div>

        <table>
        <tr>

        <?= Html::submitButton('Search',[ 'name'=>'view', 'value' => 'view', 'class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
        <?= Html::submitButton('Print',[ 'name'=>'print', 'value' => 'print','target'=> '_blank', 'class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>

        </tr>
        </table>

        <br/><br/>


    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
               <h3 class="box-title"><b>Report</b></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
     <table class="table table-hover" id="myDemoTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;">Sn.</td>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;">Fiscal Yr</td>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;">P1</td>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;">P2</td>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;">P3</td>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;">E1</td>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;">E2</td>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;">E3</td>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;">E4</td>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;">E5</td>

            </tr>
            <?php 

            $fyId=$model->fy_id;
            $companyId=$model->company_id;
            $pearlFinancial=array();

            $companyData=Yii::$app->db->createCommand("select * from company_report where fy_id='$fyId'  and company_id='$companyId' ")->queryAll();

            $sn=1;
            if (empty($companyData)) {
              return;
            }else{


            foreach($companyData as $pearl)
            {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $sn; ?></td>
                <td><?php 
                $fisYear=FiscalYear::findFiscalYearById($model->fy_id);
                echo($fisYear->fiscal_yr);

                ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $pearl['P1']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $pearl['P2']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $pearl['P3']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $pearl['E1']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $pearl['E2']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $pearl['E3']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $pearl['E4']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $pearl['E5']; ?></td>

            </tr>
            <?php
            $sn++;
            }}
            ?> 

        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

My controller is:

```
public function actionPearlFinancialReport()
{       
    $model =  new CompanyReport;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        if (isset($_POST['print'])) {
        $pdf = new Pdf([
       'mode' => Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
       'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
       'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
       'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
       'content' =>  $this->renderPartial('company_report', ['model' => $model,]), 
       'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
       'cssInline'=> '.kv-heading-1{font-size:40px}',
        'options' => ['title' => 'Pearl Financial Report'],
         'methods' => [
            'SetHeader'=>['Company Report'],
            'SetFooter'=>['{PAGENO}'],
        ]
    ]);


    $response = Yii::$app->response;
    $response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
    $headers = Yii::$app->response->headers;
    $headers->add('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');

    return $pdf->render(); 
        }

    }

    return $this->render('company_report',['model'=>$model]);
}
```

Can any one help with my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using bootstrap (which you probably are if you're using kartik widgets), you can hide anything simply by adding the hidden-print class.  Applying to your code:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'Company-report',
    'action' => ['company-report'],
    'method' => 'POST',
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'hidden-print',
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I had no idea that `mpdf` respected these `css` classes. Much more elegant than my solution, and keeps the whole report on one file.

Comment: Yes it's nice - I find it very useful

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using the same view to generate both the form and the pdf. You will probably need a separate view file for the pdf report, in which you can omit the buttons and combo boxes.

You already have code in your controller to style the report. Either inline, using `cssInline` or by including your own css file using 'cssFile'